# An object is still alive after I kill its holder in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm struggling with the next bug for hours. My program structure is as follows

[image]

The `main` function initializes a `Game` object and calls `startMainWindow()`, which initializes a `GameLogic logic` object and a `MainWindow` object (passing `logic` to it as an argument, and also `this`). **Both object are local variables in** `startMainWindow()`.

The problem is, say when the player finishes the game and I want to start the high score GUI, I call `_game.startHighScoreWindow()` from withing `MainWindow`. 
The problem is that the `GameLogic` object keeps running! I easily checked it by putting a console write command in `GameLogic.actionPerformed()`. It doesn't get released from memory. This also happens even if I call `this.dispose();` before `_game.startHighScoreWindow()`.

Why is `_gameLogic` still in memory?

Some code:

PacmanGame:

```
public void startMainWindow(int levelIndex, int levelsDone, int score) {
    gameGui = null; //desperate attempt
    highScoreGui = null;
    mainMenuGui = null;
    spaceGui = null;
    gameLogic = null;
    System.gc();

    gameLogic = new GameLogic(_sprites, _levels[levelIndex], levelsDone, score);

    gameGui = new MainWindowGui(this, gameLogic, _sprites, _levels);
}

public void startHighscoreGui(int score, String time) {
        gameGui = null;
        highScoreGui = null;
        mainMenuGui = null;
        spaceGui = null;
        gameLogic = null;
        System.gc();

        highScoreGui = new HighscoreGui(this, score, time);
    }
```

MainWindow:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private PacmanGame _game;
    private GameLogic _gameLogic;
    private GamePanel _gamePanel; //JPanel
    private ToolbarPanel _toolbarPanel; //JPanel
    private Sprite[] _sprites;
    private Level[] _levels;

    public MainWindow(PacmanGame game, GameLogic gameLogic, Sprite[] sprites, Level[] levels) {
        // create our window
        super("Pacman");

        // initialize fields
        _game = game;
        _sprites = sprites;
        _gameLogic = gameLogic;
        _levels = levels;
        this._gamePanel = new GamePanel(_gameLogic, _sprites);
        this._toolbarPanel = new ToolbarPanel(_gameLogic, sprites, this);
        ...
    }

    public void playerWon(String time) {
        Level levelObj = _gameLogic.getLevelObject();
        int nextLevelIndex = (levelObj.getNum()) % 3;

        if(_gameLogic.getLevel() == 3) //done!
        {
            this.dispose();
            _game.startHighscoreGui(_gameLogic.getScore(), time);
        }
        else //next level
        {
            _gameLogic.nextLevel(_levels[nextLevelIndex]);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
In a desperate attempt I tried making all the GUIs and GameLogic static variables in PacmanGame, and then set them to null everytime a function is called in PacmanGame. It kept acting the same as before, that is, with having all those objects local to each function.

Comment: The best way to describe your code is by showing it. Please post a [mcve] demonstrating what you're trying to do and the problem you're facing.

Comment: It's a huge program, I understand what you're saying but I simply cannot post all the relevant code. I even added a UML explaining exactly what happens

Comment: Hence the Minimal aspect. Try to reduce your code to a representative (but functional) snippet.

Comment: Actually, the UML diagram does not show (and is not capable of showing) crucial details that at the root of your problems.  For example, if the `GameLogic` is still "running" then you must have created another thread.  That's not expressible in a UML class diagram.

Comment: Added some code

Comment: You might have to analyze the heap using [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/about/screenshots.php).

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your questions:

> An object is still alive after I kill its holder in Java?

An object becomes eligible for deletion when it becomes unreachable.  Reachable means that there is some path to the object starting from either a `static` or a local variable in some stackframe of some method that has not yet returned.

And some things are "a bit special" for example, a `Thread` object remains reachable while the thread is running ... irrespective of other references to the `Thread`.  Similar things apply to objects related to the GUI.

---

> Why is _gameLogic still in memory?

It is not possible to tell without seeing the code of an MCVE.  (Your UML diagrams and English commentary don't say ... and they are not necessarily accurate anyway!)

Looking at the snippets that you posted, your `GameLogic` object could still be reachable because there is a reference to it in the `_gameLogic` field of your `MainWindow` class.  And the `MainWindow` object could still be reachable because it is displayed.

But as we said, an MCVE is necessary if you want proper answers; i.e. answers that are better than educated guesses.

It is also worth noting / repeating

- Calling `System.gc()` is a bad idea.  It rarely works.
- Prefixing variables with an underscore is not standard Java style.  (I'd call it ugly.)
- Windowing objects won't ge garbage collected if they are currently displayed.  There are hidden references (in the SWT / AWT / JVM) that ensure that windowing objects are reachable while they are displayed.
- Calling `dispose()` on class that extends `JFrame` does not clean up fields declared by the class itself.  It doesn't know about them.

Comment: Using Eclipse, is it possible to actually check what object still holds GameLogic?

Comment: Also, dispose() hides the window, and if no other instance holds GameLogic, it should be destroyed, no?

Comment: Actually, the references to non-disposed windows are not hidden. See [`Frame.getFrames()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames--) and [`Window.getOwnedWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getOwnedWindows--), which together were sufficient to get all windows prior to Java 6. Starting with Java 6, you can get all windows, including the new ownerless windows, in one go using [`Window.getWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--).

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the GameLogic object keeps running!

If something keeps running, than *you* should stop it. It's not the job of the GC.

> It doesn't get released from memory.

Again, it's not the job of the GC to release everything immediately or alike. Its only job to try hard you won't run out of memory. It does it by collecting garbage, but that's an implementation detail; it could buy you new RAM instead and it'd fine.

**Your problem is using the wrong tool for the job.**

Just provide an explicit method to terminate your `GameLogic` and you're done. For a thread running in a loop, use a `volatile boolean stop` variable to exit the loop. For a window, use `dispose`, etc....

That's all. Just forget that there's a GC. It's not there to help you with game logic.

Comment: Or, in other words, if you are able to tell that “GameLogic object keeps running”, you are already proving that the garbage collector *must not* destroy the object.

Comment: I disposed the window that contains GamrLogic and it still wasnt released from memory. Is it possible that it keeps running because of threads (timers) that run in GameLogic?

Comment: @Pilpel sure, if you have timers, you must stop them. Otherwise, they do what you have told them. And you should stop reasoning about things like “it still wasnt released from memory”. If you are able to tell the difference, the object is not garbage. In your specific case, you already said that you notice because `actionPerformed` has been invoked, so you know that there is an active event source having a reference to your `ActionListener`. So the issue is that your object is still registered to an active timer (note how the word “garbage collector” does not even appear in the description)…